# How can I solve this ODE with nonconstant coefficient?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x(1-x)f''(x) - \lambda f(x) = 0$, where $\lambda$ is just any constant.

So far, I've just tried guessing certain functional forms, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: This only has solutions simpler than hypergeometric functions or elliptic integrals when $\lambda$ is of the form $(n^2-1)/4$ for integer $n$.

Comment: @Chappers: such restriction on $\lambda$ is fine. Can you please elaborate further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x(1-x)y''(x)-\lambda y(x)=0$$
is a particular case of the hypergeometric differential equation :
$$x(1-x)y''+\left(c-(a+b+1)x\right)y'-aby=0$$
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html

In the present case : $a=\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda})$ , $b=\frac{1}{2}(-1-\sqrt{1-4\lambda})$ , $c=0$

The general solution involves the Gauss hypergeometric function  $\:_2F_1$ : 
$$y(x)=c_1\: _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda}) \:,\: \frac{1}{2}(-1-\sqrt{1-4\lambda})\:;\: 0 \:;\: x \right) +\\+ c_2\: x\:\: _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda}) \:,\: \frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{1-4\lambda})\:;\: 2 \:;\: x \right)$$
For some particular values of the parameters $a, b, c$, the hypergeometric function reduces to functions of lower level (elementary and/or special) :
https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales , pages 26-28.

Comment: do you know how to find a particular solution when this equation is nonhomogeneous? i.e. say there is a function of $x$ on the right hand side.

Comment: If the equation is $$x(1-x)y''(x)-\lambda y(x)=g(x)$$ one can search particular solution on the form  $$y=h(x)\: _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda}) \:,\: \frac{1}{2}(-1-\sqrt{1-4\lambda})\:;\: 0 \:;\: x \right)$$ This leads to a first order linear ODE which unknown is $h'(x)$. Then $h(x)$ after integration and finally $y(x)$. But this is purely formal because on this way two integrals are encountered, involving the hypergeometric function. Most probably they will not have a closed form. May be, if you are very lucky it could be successfull, depending on the function $g(x)$.